# Store time taken to run query in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to gauge performance across about 300 views with and without some changes. I can write a script easily enough to run every view, but ideally, I wanted to get the time it took for each view to run individually.

I know that you can use SET STATISTICS TIME ON, to get the time, but this would be per-query and would not be easily searchable. Ideally, I wasn't sure if the STATISTICS TIME ON has an output parameter or something, or additionally - if there is a known way to manually time a query's execution so that I can insert it somewhere?

Comment: That sounds arduous. Why not run Profiler or use Extended Events? If you need this information regularly, buy a monitoring tool.

Comment: It's really just a one-off test. The only data that I would want is whether there was a net gain or decrease in the views performance. I don't think it sounds too arduous - it's easy enough to run every view and the logic for storing the times just needs to be added alongside it.

Comment: A one-off test is even more of a reason to use built-in tooling. Why reinvent all four wheels?

Comment: I think that two more important things to check would be considering the results of SET STATISTICS IO ON to see more about what's happening behind the covers in terms of I/O and looking at the changes in the execution plan. Simply comparing the running time between two versions of code is not a robust method of comparing performance between two versions of code that presumably do the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be to look at the exec_query_stats view.
You can get the execution count and total elapsed time and a lot more, but this is only from queries that have been cached.

```
SELECT dest.TEXT AS [Query],
       (deqs.total_elapsed_time+0.0)/deqs.execution_count average_elapsed_time,
       deqs.*
  FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
 CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
 ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

You might want to issue a CHECKPOINT and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS after you've installed your new views to clear the cache.

Answer (score 2):

If you're still dead set on doing this, here's an old test harness I used to use for timing queries for comparison. I adapted it a bit to suit your circumstances using only Views.

Some notes:

- I'm diffing start and end times using milliseconds. If you want it to
  be more granular, switch to `DATETIME2` and use `MICROSECONDS` and
  change `GETDATE()` to `SYSDATETIME()`.
- I'm using a `WHILE` loop. I'm not against cursors for stuff like
  this, I just can't ever remember the darn syntax.
- I'm dumping everything into temp tables to avoid displaying the
  results of all the queries. SSMS returning and rendering results is
  abhorrently slow sometimes and can skew execution times. If tempdb is
  an issue for you, uh, good luck.
- If you run into any issues or errors in the code, there's a limited amount of troubleshooting I can do. It Works On My Machine®

Hope this helps!

```
USE /*YourDatabase*/
SET NOCOUNT ON 

CREATE TABLE dbo.ViewPerf
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ViewSchema NVARCHAR(128),
    ViewName NVARCHAR(128),
    StartTime DATETIME,
    EndTime DATETIME,
    Execution_MS AS DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, StartTime, EndTime)
);

INSERT dbo.ViewPerf (ViewSchema, ViewName )
SELECT   SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), v.name
FROM     sys.views AS v
ORDER BY v.object_id;

DECLARE @Cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @ViewSchema NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @ViewName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @MinId INT = 0;
DECLARE @MaxId INT = 0;

SELECT @MinId = MIN(vp.Id), @MaxId = MAX(vp.Id)
FROM   dbo.ViewPerf AS vp;

WHILE @MinId <= @MaxId
    BEGIN

        SELECT @ViewSchema = vp.ViewSchema,
               @ViewName = vp.ViewName 
        FROM   dbo.ViewPerf AS vp
        WHERE  vp.Id = @MinId;

        SET @Cmd = N'SELECT * INTO #' + @ViewName + N' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@ViewSchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ViewName) + N';';

        UPDATE vp
        SET    vp.StartTime = GETDATE()
        FROM   dbo.ViewPerf AS vp
        WHERE  vp.Id = @MinId;

        RAISERROR(@Cmd, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Cmd

        UPDATE vp
        SET    vp.EndTime = GETDATE()
        FROM   dbo.ViewPerf AS vp
        WHERE  vp.Id = @MinId;

        SET @MinId += 1;

    END;

SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.ViewPerf AS vp
ORDER BY vp.Id;

DROP TABLE dbo.ViewPerf
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very fancy but for a one off

```
select getdate();
select count(*) from view;
go;
select getdate();
```